# Being honest about your dismissal

Tags: recruitment, united-kingdom, termination

Its been months now, I been terminated from my previous job while I was on probation, it was a “Caseation of probation period,” due to many complicated reason e.g. I was not given priority over a native.

Now I had been getting many recruiter calls and I am ashamed to say of what I need to say i.e. “I was fired” and for a reason I cannot make sense of. I had been feeling sorry for myself as I told some recruiters that it was a contract job (as my manager told me to mention it while I was packing things up after my dismissal), while recently I mention that it was a progressive job as I thought.

And now I am 2 months without a job and I am thinking, maybe my reporting manager is giving a bad reference or something else. But what should I do when recruiters call me and how do I rectify for all other recruiters I didn’t tell right reason. Should I apologize and rectify my mistake on LinkedIn, so all recruiter can read. Will it hurt my reputation?

Comment: What does "I was not given priority over a native" mean?

Comment: It sounds like he was working abroad in competition with one or more other workers in probabtion for the same job, and the native person was given the job at the end of the probation period over OP.

Comment: @AE favouring someone for being one of their own and I was a foreigner

Comment: @Nofel Did you actually get fired though? It sounds more like the company had some sort of unannounced trial period for a position and ended up not hiring everyone who was in the running. If that was the case that's a much better explanation for why the job fell through, but your post doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @Nofel, you realise that for example in the USA you are only supposed to be hired if no "native" can be found to do the job?

Comment: @gnasher729 I m in the uk

Comment: You need to be clearer about why you were dismissed. In the UK there are strong laws protecting people from discrimination, and I am inferring you think you were discriminated against because you are not a UK citizen.

Comment: Specifically what was the reason the company gave you for your dismissal? (Whether you believe it or not).

Comment: I think saying "you were fired" is probably hurting you more than anything - and I think you're wrong to be saying that (unless there's more to the "complicated reasons" you don't mention). While it's not great being asked to continue after a probationary period, it is not the same as being fired from a position.

Comment: Do you mean, "cessation of probation period"? That just means end of probation period. Caseation has a medical definition related to tuberculosis.

Answer (score 10):

I feel there's a lot we'll never really find out about your situation, because it sounds complicated (and probably somewhere outside the US) , but I just  want to discuss this line :

> …due to many complicated reason e.g. I was not given priority over a
>   native.
>
> Now I had been getting many recruiter calls and I am ashamed to say of
>   what I need to say i.e. “I was fired” and for a reason I cannot make
>   sense of.

One thing you need to do, as a job-seeker, is to keep things positive. I know it sounds cliché and probably a little annoying, but please do keep things *positive.*

Perhaps you really were let go because the other guy was a native, but you must internalize a different reason. The other guy was the person they wanted. That's all.

Why is that important? It's important because as a job-seeker, in the job-hunt, you're going to get let down a lot. You won't get your first job, or maybe even the 376th job. You have to keep your attitude positive.

2nd point is that - you always have to say things with a positive spin. You don't say "I was fired" because it sounds too blunt (maybe you're not native-English speaker though?). You have to say things in a positive light. The employer asks "so what happened in XYZ job where you only stayed 3 months?" , and you say "This job was a learning experience for me. Though I was let go early, I took many lessons from the experience and I made sure to keep the bridges with old boss and colleagues."

But if you merely said, "Oh that job? yea.... I was fired." Then it sounds that overall, it was a bad situation. And you don't want to talk any more (bad sign?).

Hopefully you can find the best job!

Comment: Yes, well said :)

Answer (score -2):

No, you need not be too honest I feel. Whatever may be the reason you got terminated from the employement. They must be telling the reason that why you got terminated. Ideally, they will never tell due you your poor performance or whatever may be the reason that reflects negative on you on the feedback. They will just tell your contract has been completed and they are not willing to renew or under a situation that they cannot continue it.

Just tell in the interview if anyone asks you, that your contract with your previous organization is completed.

Also, please have a positive attitude towards your life and career. If you are very strong in your business, things don't even matter for your next employers/recruiter as long you are confident on your life.

Have a good luck and all the very best for your career.

Comment: Any reason or justification for downvotes pls?

Comment: Probably the fact that if you lie about leaving because your contract ended, and they check your references, you are absolutely guaranteed to not get the job.

Comment: Thank you.. any suggestible edits? or should I bring the post down?

Comment: Even though it is horrible advice, I would probably do exactly this. At least would have when I was younger. It is the most natural way to go about it before thinking it through. Knowing me, back then, I wouldn't even put a 3 month job on there, just say been out of work for 5 months.